# firebase.messaging() causes PWA to lock up on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I've just developed a NUXTJS app as a PWA and it works fine on my android and laptop machines. But it doesn't work on IOS devices. Ive packaged this up and deployed this to firebase hosting.
This is what I see on IOS devices and I am not sure how to debug it. It's just an orange loading icon which goes on forever. The app was tested on IPhones and Ipads using both chrome browser and safari.

[image]

I have developed other NUXTjs applications before, and done the same procedure of deploying it to firebase hosting and it works for both IOS and Android. So I believe, it must be some package I've added that has caused it to be this way. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to debug on an iphone or ipad. It would really help if I could access a console to see the printouts. FYI, I don't have a MAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the offender.

In my firebase init.js file

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/messaging";

var config = {
  //settings
};

!firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : "";
export const GoogleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const persistencetype = firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;

export const firestoreDB = firebase.firestore().collection("").doc("");
export const firestore = firebase.firestore;
export const storage = firebase.app().storage("");

export const messaging = firebase.messaging(); // THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE

export default firebase;
```

For some reason, the export const messaging = firebase.messaging() doesn't work on IOS
Perhaps someone from the Firebase team can shed some light on this?
I am using version    "firebase": "^7.14.3",

```
    "@firebase/messaging": {
      "version": "0.6.15",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase/messaging/-/messaging-0.6.15.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-WswV3JtxAgqc0LPQtIBdMWJdMhVZu7gKF6MO5ETIpNaLZZ0QayYNu5+G9btoZz218HB/gvUp2NFX43OWAsqdZw==",
      "requires": {
        "@firebase/component": "0.1.11",
        "@firebase/installations": "0.4.9",
        "@firebase/messaging-types": "0.4.4",
        "@firebase/util": "0.2.46",
        "idb": "3.0.2",
        "tslib": "1.11.1"
      }
    },
```

I replicated the problem in this repo
https://github.com/limjix/firebasecloudmessagingbug